# Magento 2 - Prohibits depends directly the ObjectManager, but all object can use factory object

Tags: magento2, object, factory

As Magento prohibits depending on and directly using the **ObjectManager**, whether all object can use **factory object** to instantiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: YES.
Long answer.
All the objects that are not instantiated directly using `new` can have a factory.
By that I mean if you have a class `Some\ClassName` and you try to instantiate the factory class for this class that does not exist `new Some\ClassNameFactory` most probably it will not work.

But any factory that does not exist but it used as a dependency for an other class gets automatically generated as long as the class name ends with the keyword `Factory`.

Example:
You have this constructor

```
public function construct(
    SomeClassFactory $someClassFactory,
    OtherClassFactory $otherClassFactory, 
    EvenOneMoreFactory $evenOneMoreFactory
) {
    ....
}
```

if the classes `SomeClass`, `OtherClass` and `EventOneMore` exist, the factories will be autogenerated.

If you manually created the classes `SomeClassFactory`, `OtherClassFactory` or `EventOneMoreFactory` for some reason, they will not be autogenerated anymore. Your factory classes will be used.

Comment: thx, Marius. is there any object can not use Factory Object to instantiate in magento 2?

Comment: what is “ non-injectable ”classes， the official docs says Factories are service classes that instantiate non-injectable classes.